# I want to get Decription value from recordtype using lightning component/LWC without auery(Apex). is It possible?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

[image]

You can see my image in which available description field's value get using lightning component or lightning web component without using apex.

Comment: I guess you need to use apex only.

Comment: Ok thanks rahul.